# Chacuopy 15.0 was not found

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, chaquopy, f#-giraffe

I try to setup chaquopy version 15.0 on Giraffe, checked everywhere, and cannot find the solution.
I have Gradle version 8.1.1
Followed instructions from chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/15.0/
according documentation gradle is compatible and schould work. but I get

> org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.chaquo.python', version: '15.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

build.gradle - project level

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
id("com.chaquo.python") version "15.0.0" apply false
}
```

Gradle App level

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
id("com.chaquo.python")
}
```

Settings gradle

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()

 }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()

}
}

rootProject.name = "botTest"
include(":app")
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaquopy 15 has not been released yet, but it should be available within the next couple of weeks. Until then, you can use a pre-release build as shown [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/934#issuecomment-1683205265):

> - At the top level of your project, edit the settings.gradle or build.gradle file to add this line to the `repositories` block within `pluginManagement` or `buildscript` (NOT within `allprojects` or `dependencyResolutionManagement`):
>
> ```
> maven { url = uri("https://chaquo.com/maven-test") }
> ```
>
> - Edit the build.gradle file to change the Chaquopy version to `15.0.0`.
> - In KTS files, you'll need to configure Chaquopy using a top-level `chaquopy` block, rather than the `python` block within `android`. For details, see the [Chaquopy 15 documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/15.0/android.html).